# How to turn an Indy UTF-8 response into a native Delphi (Unicode)String?

Tags: delphi, utf-8, character-encoding, delphi-2010, indy

Using Indy `THTTP` I obtain a response that has `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8` and store it in a `TStringStream`. If I then use `ReponseStream.ReadString(ResponseStream.Size)`, the resulting `String` is not correctly shown. I bet this is due to the fact that Windows uses UTF-16.

I tried a few things with `TEncoding.UTF8` and `TEncoding.Convert` that only messed up the result even more (started to look Chinese).

Here's the current code:

```
var
  LHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  LResponseStream: TStringStream;
  LResponse: String;
begin
  LResponseStream := TStringStream.Create();
  try
    LHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
    try
      LHTTP.Get('url', LResponseStream); // Returns 'hęllo'
    finally
      LHTTP.Free;
    end;
    LResponseStream.Position := 0;
    LResponse := LResponseStream.ReadString(LResponseStream.Size);
    ShowMessage(LResponse); // Make me pretty
  finally
    LResponseStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

What should I change to get a regular Delphi `String`...?

Comment: The `TStringStream` constructor has an overload where you can specify encoding to be used. Or you can call [`UTF8Decode`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.UTF8Decode) before you assign the `ReadString` result to your `LResponse` variable. Or you can simply use a `TIdHTTP.Get` overload which returns `string` and decode it with the mentioned `UTF8Decode` function, which will save you the whole stream stuff.

Comment: Oh, that wasn't so bad then. Care to make your own answer out of this or shall I accept aleroot's?

Comment: @TLama `UTF8Decode` seems to work differently; it turns ę into e.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TIdHTTP has an overloaded version of Get() that returns a String. It will decode the UTF-8 into UTF-16 for you:

```
LResponse := LHTTP.Get('url');
```

Comment: Hurray for simplicity.

Answer (score 4):

If the content you are trying to download is encoded as UTF-8 character set, you could simply force TStringStream to re-encode that data to UTF-8 internally in this way :

```
LResponseStream := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.UTF8);
```